# MySql array type and default value

Tags: mysql

I need add field with default value like that

```
`setting_notification` = 'a:2:{s:19:"other_notifications";i:1;s:21:"message_notifications";i:0;}' 

ALTER TABLE app_users ADD setting_notification tinytext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:array)'
```

How can do this ?

I try this

```
ALTER TABLE app_users 
ADD setting_notification LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 
DEFAULT 'a:2:{s:19:"other_notifications";i:1;s:21:"message_notifications";i:0;}'  
COMMENT '(DC2Type:array)'
```

And have error

```
 [Err] 1101 - BLOB, TEXT, GEOMETRY or JSON column 'setting_notification' can't have a default value
```

and try like that

```
ALTER TABLE app_users 
ADD setting_notification tinytext 
DEFAULT "a:2:{s:19:\"other_notifications\";i:1;s:21:\"message_notifications\";i:0;}" 
COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci 
NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:array)'
```

still have error

```
[Err] 1101 - BLOB, TEXT, GEOMETRY or JSON column 'setting_notification' can't have a default value
```

sql version

```
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-------------------------+
| VERSION()               |
+-------------------------+
| 5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0,01 sec)
```

Comment: what mysql version?

Comment: `mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-------------------------+
| VERSION()               |
+-------------------------+
| 5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0,01 sec)

`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a default value. Why do you use tinytext and not varchar?

```
ALTER TABLE app_users ADD setting_notification varchar(255) DEFAULT "a:2:{s:19:\"other_notifications\";i:1;s:21:\"message_notifications\";i:0;}" COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:array)'
```

Comment: `[Err] 1101 - BLOB, TEXT, GEOMETRY or JSON column 'setting_notification' can't have a default value`

Comment: Is there any reason to use tinytext as a data type? Use varchar and you should be fine.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE app_users 
ADD setting_notification VARCHAR 
DEFAULT "a:2:{s:19:\"other_notifications\";i:1;s:21:\"message_notifications\";i:0;}" 
COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci 
NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:array)'`

`[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DEFAULT "a:2:{s:19:\"other_notifications\";i:1;s:21:\"message_notifications\";i:' at line 15`

Comment: I added a length to the varchar data type. But I do not know how long it should be. Please adjust this.